# My MERN app works during development but breaks when deployed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, mern

I have been working on an app that was built with the MERN stack. My app works perfectly in my development server but breaks when i deploy it to heroku.

Please can anyone give me a hint of what is wrong. Please my job is on the line

Here's the error
[A picture of the Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5pZF.jpg)

"react": "^16.13.1",
"node": "12.16.1",
"npm": "6.14.6"

Comment: first try this. Delete your node_modules, clear npm/yarn cache, delete your lock file. The re install npm's in your local. See you get the problem in your local or not. 

in case in need to add heroko prehook to install your npm. read about on the heroku documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Well dude you dont provide to much information about the error , but i will made some assumptions, if you see the img of the error will see that error t.map is not a function , just check a AdminDashboard.js: 63 , is map is not a function is obviusly that t is not array or is a type that have .map method, just check where t get assigned value i am not sure but probablly when you go to prod this t value is not array and in dev mode is pollutaing with an array, just debug it and will find the eror : )

Comment: I dont have "t.map" in "AdminDashboard.js :63".

Comment: on that line one function are calling another function and inside it has the that t.map, just debug ,just trace what function are the first caller, or just paste here